=IFERROR(Rounddown(datedif(B2,C2,"D")/7)) Make this show the weeks up to the date even if I don't have an end date yet
In google sheets I am using this formula to currently calculate the amount of time that has taken place between two dates. =IFERROR(Rounddown(datedif(B2,C2,"D")/7))
Is there something I can add to this formula to make it show the number of weeks up to todays current date? Currently it only shows me the weeks between the dates if I have an end date.
I think I showed above, that is all I have tried. I am not sure what to google to get the results Im looking for.

Here's another method you may try:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2:A)), ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B = "", FLOOR((NOW()-A2:A)/7), FLOOR((B2:B-A2:A)/7))), " "))



This should also resolve the part where you're getting random numbers on cells that don't have any start and end dates.


you can use this
=IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(DATEDIF(B2, IF(C2="", TODAY(), C2), "D")/7), "")
here is the example,


That worked! But now if a cell has both empty dates it is given me a number. What do I need to add to make it so if there is no start date or end date it ignores it so it doesn't populate a random number

You can use if statement at the beginning, so if both days are empty, the cell should be empty, you can try this =IF(OR(B2="", C2=""), "", IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(DATEDIF(B2, IF(C2="", TODAY(), C2), "D")/7, 0), ""))
